# simple connected but not complete graph has an induced path of length 2.

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a simple connected but not complete graph. Show that $G$ has an induced path of length $2$.

This is my argument so far. I think I've very close but I just need a little push in the correct direction.

Let $S=\{(x,v):xv\notin E(G)\}$, Since $G$ is not complete $S$ is non empty. Since $G$ is connected, for each $(x,y)\in S$ there exists a path $x v_{1}v_{2}\cdots v_{n} y$. $G$ is simple so writing a path in this fashion is kosher. Take a path of minimal length over all such paths, call it $P$. I want to show that $P$ has length 2.

So far I have deduced that $x$ can not be adjacent to $v_{i}$ for $i>1$ or else we could shorten the path. But that is as far as I have gotten.

**EDIT**
Ok I think I've completed but it's late and I may be confused. Assume that $n\geq 1$. If $x$ were connected to $v_{i}$ for $i\neq 1$ then we could shorten the path by removing $v_{1}$. Therefore $x$ and $v_{2}$ say are not connected. Therefore $(x,v_{2})\in S$ and the path $xv_{1}v_{2}$ will exist which will induce a path of length 2.

Any hints would be must appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no need to look at minimal paths.

Suppose that $G$ has no induced path of length $2$, and let $v_0$ be any vertex of $G$. Let $N(v_0)$ be the set of vertices $v$ such that $\{v_0,v\}$ is an edge of $G$.

- Show that if $N(v_0)=\varnothing$, then $G=K_1$, so $N(v_0)\ne\varnothing$.
- Show that if $u,w\in N(v_0)$ with $u\ne w$, then $uv_0w$ is an induced path of length $2$ in $G$, so $N(v_0)$ cannot contain two distinct vertices.
- Show that if $N(v_0)=\{u\}$ for some vertex $u$ and hence that either $G$ is not connected, or $G=K_2$.
- Conclude that since all cases lead to a contradiction, $G$ must have an induced path of length $2$.